Borb RegularExpressionTextExtraction "AssertionError: A Rectangle must have a non-negative width."
I see a similar question has been asked (A Rectangle must have a non-negative height), but I can't figure out how to proceed with the answer... Also, it looks a bit different. Anyway:
I've amended code I found here (https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#53-extracting-text-using-regular-expressions) into C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf\stringsuitpdf.py. I've also got a pdf: C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf\Jim.pdf. It's rather large: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ykr26QNVb8aK6hPdh0pikkEVRScSCBX/view?usp=sharing.
This is the code:
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_006.py
import typing

from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import RegularExpressionTextExtraction


teonderzoekenpdf = "Jim.pdf"
zoekstring = 'Cited by'

def main():
    
    # read the Document
    # fmt: off
    print("Stap 2")
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: RegularExpressionTextExtraction = RegularExpressionTextExtraction(zoekstring)
    with open(teonderzoekenpdf, "rb") as in_file_handle:
        print("Stap 3")
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])
        print("Stap 3,5")
    # fmt: on

    # check whether we have read a Document
    print("Stap 4")
    assert doc is not None
    print("Stap 5")
 
    # print matching groups
    for i, m in enumerate(l.get_matches()[0]):
        print("Stap 6")
        print("%d %s" % (i, m.group(0)))
        #for r in m.get_bounding_boxes():
            #print(
            #    "\t%f %f %f %f" % (r.get_x(), r.get_y(), r.get_width(), r.get_height())
            #)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Stap 1")
    main()

This is the output:
PS C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf'; & 'c:\Python312\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Erik\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51988' '--' 'c:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf\stringsuitpdf.py' 
Stap 1
Stap 2
Stap 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf\stringsuitpdf.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Strings_uit_pdf\stringsuitpdf.py", line 29, in main
    doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\pdf.py", line 85, in loads
    document: Document = ReadAnyObjectTransformer().transform(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\reference\xref_transformer.py", line 305, in transform
    trailer = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\object\dictionary_transformer.py", line 69, in transform
    v = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\reference\reference_transformer.py", line 169, in transform
    transformed_referenced_object = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\page\root_dictionary_transformer.py", line 112, in transform
    transformed_root_dictionary = t.transform(
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\object\dictionary_transformer.py", line 69, in transform
    v = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\reference\reference_transformer.py", line 169, in transform
    transformed_referenced_object = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\object\dictionary_transformer.py", line 69, in transform
    v = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\object\array_transformer.py", line 69, in transform
    object_to_transform[i] = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\reference\reference_transformer.py", line 169, in transform
    transformed_referenced_object = self.get_root_transformer().transform(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\any_object_transformer.py", line 113, in transform
    return super().transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\transformer.py", line 149, in transform
    out = h.transform(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\io\read\page\page_dictionary_transformer.py", line 129, in transform
    CanvasStreamProcessor(page_out, canvas, []).read(
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\canvas_stream_processor.py", line 277, in read
    raise e
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\canvas_stream_processor.py", line 271, in read
    operator.invoke(self, operands, event_listeners)
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\operator\text\show_text_with_glyph_positioning.py", line 84, in invoke
    l._event_occurred(tri)
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\toolkit\text\regular_expression_text_extraction.py", line 326, in _event_occurred
    self._render_text(event)
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\toolkit\text\regular_expression_text_extraction.py", line 338, in _render_text
    for e in text_render_info.split_on_glyphs():
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\event\chunk_of_text_render_event.py", line 177, in split_on_glyphs
    e._baseline_bounding_box = Rectangle(
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\canvas\geometry\rectangle.py", line 30, in __init__
    assert width >= 0, "A Rectangle must have a non-negative width."
           ^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: A Rectangle must have a non-negative width.

I'm only looking for text, so I don't see what the rectangle has to do with anything... But there are some boxes in the document, so maybe that's where the error comes from?
Anyway, I would love to be able to fetch a list of mentions of my substring, and possibly a page number of every mention.
If anyone knows what I could do to get this to work, that would be great!
Thanks in advance!

The text layer of a PDF file is just a collection of characters/character mappings. To extract/render the text, one approach is to collect all bounding boxes and sort them by their x and y values accordingly to generate the actual text - this is what borb seem s to do here as well. This specific issue either is about a broken PDF file or a bug in borb which should be reported there.

I thought I had, but that it was removed, because I should have posted a question here. But I now see I opened an issue in the wrong repository... (https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples/issues/46)
